# Ruby on Rails bundle exec rake assets:precompile error - no such file to load -- gelf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, bundler, assets

When I run RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile I get:

```
Rake aborted!
no such file to load -- gelf

Tasks: TOP => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
rake aborted!
```

if I run it with --trace I get:

```
** Invoke assets:precompile:all (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile:all
** Invoke assets:precompile:primary (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- gelf
/Users/gareth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/Users/gareth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/Users/gareth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/Users/gareth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/Users/gareth/enghance/config/initializers/graylog.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

I havent been able to find any solution, or question with the same error so I'm thinking it might be something basic.

Is there anyone who has had the same problem and figured it out or knows what's going wrong?

Comment: Is there any other relevant code? Does the error point to a specific part of the app (with a line number, maybe)?

Comment: What is gelf and why does `config/initializers/graylog.rb` need it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the gelf gem, in your gemfile, resulting in the error:

```
no such file to load -- gelf
```

Simply add the following line to your gemfile:

```
gem 'gelf'
```

And run `bundle install`, from the root of your app.

Comment: Thanks! I know that was obvious but it was only part of the problem. I had previously tried to depoy with 'rubber' and couldn't get it to work so when I removed it I missed some configuration files properly.

Comment: Could you tell me how you came to fix your problem? I'm having the same issue with rubber (apparently it doesn't work on Windows and I found out too late) and since there isn't a way to properly uninstall my app is a mess. - NEVERMIND! I had to stay up all night but I finally fixed everything by deleting every single file that came with rubber.

Answer (score 1):

I realize that this response is outrageously late, but if someone eles comes across the problem, I thought I'd share how I got around it - it's very easy once you've worked it out (in my case that took several hours :( ).  I had decided to deploy my rails app on EC-2 and was following a rubber + rails + EC2 tutorial, but I couldn't get it to work.  I reverted to an earlier git checkpoint, thinking that it would get rid of all the stuff from rubber on my system - but it didn't.  Each time I'd try to run "rails server", I'd get an error relating to rubber, the first of which was the one you mentioned above:
`in require': cannot load such file -- gelf (LoadError)`

After deleting the following files, everything went back to working:

`config/rubber`

`config/initializers/graylog.rb`

Just in case it helps anyone else.